# MySQL: how to convert to EAV?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

Say I have the following table:

```
TABLE: one
===============================
| id | first_name | last_name |
===============================
| 1  | John       | Doe       |
| 2  | Jane       | Smith     |
-------------------------------
```

I want to convert it to an EAV:

```
TABLE: two
===================================
| id | fk_id | attribute  | value |
===================================
| 1  | 1     | first_name | John  |
| 2  | 1     | last_name  | Doe   |
| 3  | 2     | first_name | Jane  |
| 4  | 2     | last_name  | Smith |
-----------------------------------
```

Note:

- two.fk_id values came from one.id
- two.attribute values came from one.first_name
- two.value values came from one.last_name

I need to create table two from table one so I can run some tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming two.id is an autoincrementing integer, so I'll leave it to the target table to assign those values.

```
select id as fk_id, 'first_name' as attribute, first_name as value
from one
union all
select id as fk_id, 'last_name', last_name
from one
order by fk_id, attribute
```

Answer (score 0):

For the love of god, don't use EAV!!!!
If you need that, use a NoSQL database instead!

Comment: Sorry, this was not a question about pros and cons of EAV. I just need to know how to convert table one into table two.