# MySQL: how to convert to EAV - Part 2?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-attribute-value

Here's Part 1: [MySQL: how to convert to EAV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020661/mysql-how-to-convert-to-eav)

Now I want to also do something different. Say I have the following table:

```
TABLE: one
=======================================
| id | fk_id | attribute  | value     |
=======================================
| 1  | 10    | first_name | John      |
| 2  | 10    | last_name  | Doe       |
| 3  | 55    | first_name | Bob       |
| 4  | 55    | last_name  | Smith     |
---------------------------------------
```

I want to convert it to this EAV model:

```
TABLE: attribute
===================
| id | attribute  |
===================
| 1  | first_name |
| 2  | last_name  |
-------------------

TABLE: value
=====================================
| id | attribute_id | fk_id | value |
=====================================
| 1  | 1            | 10    | John  |
| 2  | 2            | 10    | Doe   |
| 3  | 1            | 55    | Bob   |
| 4  | 2            | 55    | Smith |
-------------------------------------
```

Assume the tables `attribute` and `value` are already defined. How do I insert the data from table `one` into the two target tables. One big problem for me is how to get the relationship (`attribute.id` => `value.attribute_id`) right.

Comment: Following to your problems - do you still think it does worth to move to?!

Comment: I am doing this to do some tests. I'm not sue if I do have problems yet. I'm trying to figure out if I will encounter problems in the future. For now, I just need to convert my data in these various EAV models so I can run some tests.

Comment: you haven't even started working with it but you already got issues... For myself I decided never to use EAV anymore

Comment: My "issue" right now is to re-model my current data into EAV. This issue is not an issue of the EAV model itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO attribute
  (attribute)
SELECT DISTINCT
  attribute
FROM one ;

INSERT INTO value
  (attribute_id, fk_id, value)
SELECT 
  attribute.id, one.fk_id, one.value
FROM one
  JOIN attribute
    ON attribute.attribute = one.attribute ;
```